# Implementing a multimap in Swift with Arrays and Dictionaries

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a basic multimap in Swift. Here's a relevant (non-functioning) snippet:

```
class Multimap<K: Hashable, V> {
    var _dict = Dictionary<K, V[]>()

    func put(key: K, value: V) {
        if let existingValues = self._dict[key] {
            existingValues += value
        } else {
            self._dict[key] = [value]
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error on the `existingValues += value` line:

```
Could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

This seems to imply that the value type `T[]` is defined as an immutable array, but I can't find any way to explicitly declare it as mutable. Is this possible in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if var existingValues = self._dict[key] { //var, not let
    existingValues += value;
    // should set again.
    self._dict[key] = existingValues
} else {
    self._dict[key] = [value]
}
```

> Assignment and Copy Behavior for Arrays
>   The assignment and copy behavior for Swift’s Array type is more complex than for its Dictionary type. Array provides C-like performance when you work with an array’s contents and copies an array’s contents only when copying is necessary.
>
> If you assign an Array instance to a constant or variable, or pass an Array instance as an argument to a function or method call, the contents of the array are not copied at the point that the assignment or call takes place. Instead, both arrays share the same sequence of element values. When you modify an element value through one array, the result is observable through the other.
>
> For arrays, **copying only takes place when you perform an action that has the potential to modify the length of the array**. This includes appending, inserting, or removing items, or using a ranged subscript to replace a range of items in the array. If and when array copying does take place, the copy behavior for an array’s contents is the same as for a dictionary’s keys and values, as described in Assignment and Copy Behavior for Dictionaries.

See: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11

Comment: To be explicit, the docs quoted above mean that while changing `let` to `var` fixes the compile-time error, you won't see any values beyond the first stick if you don't reassign the key in the dictionary. I was hoping to avoid reassignment but it appears to be impossible to do so.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are defining `existingValues` as a constant with `let`. However, I would suggest changing the method to be:

```
func put(key: K, value: V) {
        var values = [value]
        if let existingValues = self._dict[key] {
            values.extend(existingValues)
        }
        self._dict[key] = values
    }
}
```

I feel that the intent of this is clearer as it doesn't require modifying the local array and reassigning later.

Answer (score 1):

[Buckets](https://github.com/mauriciosantos/Buckets-Swift#buckets) is a data structures library for swift. It provides a multimap and allows subscript notation.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to implement a multi-map is to use a list of pairs (key, value) sorted by key, using binary search to find ranges of entries. This works best when you need to get a bunch of data, all at once. It doesn't work so well when you are constantly deleting and inserting elements.

See [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) from C++ for a binary search implementation which can be easily written in swift.