# Swift:How to map a single key to Multiple values?

Tags: ios, swift

I have successfully mapped a Single key to single value like this:

```
    class DefaultDoubleModel :BaseObject
{
    var key : String = ""
    var value : String = ""
}

      var toolChart :[DefaultDoubleModel]!
       self.BubbleChartXaxislabel = Array(GraphDataModel.toolChart.map({ (item) -> String in
                        item.key
                    }))
                    self.BubbleChartValuesGraph = Array(GraphDataModel.toolChart.map({ (item) -> String in
                        item.value
                    }))
```

This is true for single key and single value. But i have two values in a single key. How can i collect those values in array.

For example i have like this..

```
{"value2":"80","value1":"120","key":"4"}
```

Comment: You want something like a multi map (for example in C++). Swift does not have it, here is an approach to implement it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197186/implementing-a-multimap-in-swift-with-arrays-and-dictionaries

Comment: Except you mean exactly two values each time, then use tuples.

Comment: yes exactly two values at each time.

Answer (score 0):

A Dictionary with tuples of strings would look like this:

```
var data: [String: (String, String)]()
data["4"] = ("80", "120")
print(data["4"]!.0)
```

You access the elements as .0 and .1.

Comment: can you please go according to my question as above??or what should i do above

Comment: I am not sure I understand your code completely. If you want to build the datastructure yourself, you could add `var value2: String = ""` in DefaultDoubleModel and access that value somehow in the BubbleChart...

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly two values, then you can make your `DefaultDoubleModel` look like this

```
class DefaultDoubleModel :BaseObject {
    var key : String = ""
    var value1 : String = ""
    var value2 : String = ""
}
```

I think its more future proof to make it an array of Strings, like this:

```
class DefaultDoubleModel :BaseObject {
    var key : String = ""
    var values = [String]()
}
```

If you go with the second option, then you would map like this:

```
self.BubbleChartValuesGraph = GraphDataModel.toolChart.flatMap{ $0.values }
```

Comment: and how can i map them..?

Comment: What is the type of `self.BubbleChartValuesGraph`?

Comment: array of strings :var BubbleChartValuesGraph : [String]!

Comment: And the self.BubbleChartValuesGraph will get exactly double the number of values as self.BubbleChartXaxislabel? That sounds odd.

Comment: So its not getting. What should i do here..? make array or array

Comment: However, @Gerriet question is valid.  It's not clear how this fits in the rest of your codebase, so I can tell you how to convert an array of arrays to a single array, but I can't tell you how to use the data

Comment: For displaying using Charts, you probably want two BubbleChartDataSet: `graph1 = GraphDataModel.toolChart.flatMap { $0.value1 }` and `graph2 = GraphDataModel.toolChart.flatMap { $0.value2 }`

Comment: `class DefaultDoubleModel {
    var key : String = ""
    var value1 : String = ""
    var value2 : String = ""
}

var toolChart = [DefaultDoubleModel]()

let a = toolChart.count
let graph1 = toolChart.map { return $0.value1 }
let graph2 = toolChart.map { return $0.value2 }`